# How to update a pivot table using Eloquent in laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am new to laravel. I am working on a laravel 5 app and I am stuck here. I have 2 models as such:

```
class Message extends Eloquent{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'from');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('status');
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent {

    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'from');
    }

    public function receive_messages() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Message')->withPivot('status');
    }
}
```

There exist a many-to-many relationship between Message and User giving me a pivot table as such:

```
Table Name: message_user
Colums:
message_id
user_id
status
```

I have an SQL query as such:

```
update message_user
set status = 1
where user_id = 4 and message_id in (select id from messages where message_id = 123)
```

How can I translate this query to the laravel equivalent?

Comment: Dude what do you mean by `from`?

Comment: Foreign key @Mohamed

Comment: dude the second argument is the conjunction table name, in your example it should be 'message_user' , the total right relation for **messages** in **User** model :
`return $this->hasMany('App\Message\,'message_user','user_id','message_id');`

Comment: No dude. You are missing the point. Check out the laravel documentation. This can help: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: @Mohamed the docs has something like so: return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');

Comment: buddy I just checked it, I'm sure about it, in same link that you've send me search for this line please: `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id');`

Comment: @Mohamed `from` is on  `return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'from');` on my post. Look at the post again. It's on the 1 to many relationship.

Comment: Ok I got, sorry, now could you explain how do you want one to many and many to many relationships between same two tables? `users` , `messages`

Comment: Thanks for the input dude. A user can create 1 or more messages. A message can be received by 1 or more users. A user can receive 0 or more messages.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The code below solved my problem:

```
$messages  = Message::where('message_id', $id)->get();
foreach($messages as $message)
   $message->users()->updateExistingPivot($user, array('status' => 1), false);
```

Comment: Can I know what is `false` mean?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur determines if you want to update `updated_at` column timestamp

Answer (score 20):

You may use [one of these two functions](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships), `sync()` `attach()` and the difference in a nutshell is that Sync will get array as its first argument and sync it with pivot table *(remove and add the passed keys in your array)* which means if you got 3,2,1 as valued within your junction table, and passed sync with values of, 3,4,2, sync automatically will remove value 1 and add the value 4 for you. where Attach will take single ID value

**The GIST:** if you want to add extra values to your junction table, pass it as the second argument to `sync()` like so:

```php
$message = Messages::find(123);
$user = User::find(4);

// using attach() for single message
$user->message()->attach($message->id, [
    'status' => 1
]);



$message2 = Messages::find(456); // for testing

// using sync() for multiple messages
$user->message()->sync([
    $message->id => [
        'status' => 1
    ],
    $message2->id => [
        'status' => 1
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @Mohamed. Sync didn't do the trick for me.

Comment: @FokwaBest dude based on your comment above, you want only many to many relationship, therefore there is a misleading with your eloquent relations, if you want I can update my answer and write the right relations and after that `sync()` will work :)

Comment: dude actually when a user creates a message, is stored in the messages table. The pivot table just keep a record of the message_id and the recipient ($user_id). It's working pretty well now but I would love to see your approach anyway.

Comment: Thanks @MohamedKawsara! I just want to notice everybody the most important `false` flag in `sync()` method call. Because if it's not passed, all other records different than current $message->id will be detached. Also, notice that when we attach, method call is `attach( $id, ['attr1' => 'val1'])` but at `sync()` call we have 

```sync([$id **=>** ['attr1' => 'val1']]);```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a small example of how to update the pivot table column

```
    $query = Classes::query();
    $query = $query->with('trainees')
                   ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
                   ->find($input['classId']);

    foreach ($query->trainees as $trainee) {
       $trainee->pivot->status = 1 //your column;
       $trainee->pivot->save();
    }
```

Note: make sure your relation data must in an array
Hope its help you :)
happy coding

Answer (score 6):

**Laravel 5.8**

First, allow your pivot columns to be searchable by chaining the `withPivot` method to your `belongsToMany`

Copied from my own code to save time

```
// I have 3 columns in my Pivot table which I use in a many-to-many and one-to-many-through scenarios

$task = $user->goalobjectives()->where(['goal_objective_id'=>$goal_objective_id,'goal_obj_add_id'=>$goal_obj_add_id])->first(); //get the first record

$task->pivot->goal_objective_id = $new; //change your col to a new value

$task->pivot->save(); //save
```

The caveat is that your pivot table needs to have a primary `'id'` key.

If you don't want that then you can try the following:

```
$tasks=$user->posts()->where(['posts_id'=>$posts_id,'expires'=>true])->get()->pluck('id'); // get a collection of your pivot table data tied to this user

$key=join(",",array_keys($tasks->toArray(),$valueYouWantToRemove));

$tasks->splice($key,1,$newValueYouWantToInsert);

$c = array_fill(0,$tasks->count(),['expires'=>true]); //make an array containing your pivot data

$newArray=$tasks->combine($c) //combine the 2 arrays as keys and values

$user->posts()->sync($newArray); //your pivot table now contains only the values you want
```

**4th July Update** Update to above snippet.

```
//Ideally, you should do a check see if this user is new
//and if he already has data saved in the junction table
//or are we working with a brand new user

$count = $user->goalobjectives->where('pivot.goal_obj_add_id',$request->record)->count();

//if true, we retrieve all the ids in the junction table 
//where the additional pivot column matches that which we want to update

if($count) {

$ids = $user->goalobjectives->where('pivot.goal_obj_add_id',$request->record)->pluck('id');

//convert to array

$exists = $ids->toArray();

//if user exists and both saved and input data are exactly the same
//there is no need
//to update and we redirect user back

if(array_sum($inputArray) == array_sum($exists)) {

//redirect user back

}

//else we update junction table with a private function
//called 'attachToUser'

$res = $this->attachToUser($user, $inputArray, $ids, $request->record);

}//end if

elseif(!$count) {

//we are working with a new user
//we build an array. The third pivot column must have equal rows as
//user input array

$fill = array_fill(0,count($inputArray),['goal_obj_add_id'=>$request->record]);

//combine third pivot column with user input

$new = array_combine($inputArray,$fill);

//junction table updated with 'user_id','goal_objective_id','goal_obj_add_id'

$res = $user->goalobjectives()->attach($new);

//redirect user if success

}

//our private function which takes care of updating the pivot table

private function attachToUser(User $user, $userData, $storedData, $record) {

//find the saved data which must not be deleted using intersect method

$intersect = $storedData->intersect($userData);

if($intersect->count()) {

//we reject any data from the user input that already exists in the database

$extra = collect($userData)->reject(function($value,$key)use($intersect){

return in_array($value,$intersect->toArray());

});

//merge the old and new data

$merge = $intersect->merge($extra);

//same as above we build a new input array

$recArray = array_fill(0,$merge->count(),['goal_obj_add_id'=>$record]);

//same as above, combine them and form a new array

$new = $merge->combine($recArray);

//our new array now contains old data that was originally saved
//so we must remove old data linked to this user
// and the pivot record to prevent duplicates

$storedArray = $storedData->toArray();

$user->goalobjectives()->wherePivot('goal_obj_add_id',$record)->detach($storedArray);

//this will save the new array without detaching
//other data previously saved by this user

$res = $user->goalobjectives()->wherePivot('goal_obj_add_id',$record)->syncWithoutDetaching($new);

}//end if

//we are not working with a new user
//but input array is totally different from saved data
//meaning its new data

elseif(!$intersect->count()) {

$recArray = array_fill(0,count($userData),['goal_obj_add_id'=>$record]);

$new = $storedData->combine($recArray);

$res = $user->goalobjectives()->wherePivot('goal_obj_add_id',$record)->syncWithoutDetaching($new);

}

//none of the above we return false

return !!$res;

}//end attachToUser function
```

This will work for pivot table which doesn't have a primary auto increment id. without a auto increment id, user cannot update,insert,delete any row in the pivot table by accessing it directly.

Answer (score 3):

For Updating your pivot table you can use updateExistingPivot method.

Comment: Thanks @Babar. Can you add any sample code on how I  may use the method to come with the query on the post.

Comment: You can see documentation at http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables 

Reference code to do so is

User::find(1)->roles()->updateExistingPivot($roleId, $attributes);