# inserting data into database laravel 5.6 relation belongstomany pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

i wonder to know how to insert data into pivot table when using a belongsto many relationship i can read the data from database now but i dont know how to store data in database and in my invoice_product table here is the code
model of invoce :

```
   class Invoice extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title','description','client_id','product_id'];
    public function user() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Client','id','client_id');
    }
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'invoice_product', 'invoice_id')
            ->withPivot('product_quantity')
            ->as('invoice_products_pivot');

    }
}
```

controller of invoice :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //Validate
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|min:3',
        'description' => 'required',
    ]);

    $invoices = Invoice::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'client_id' => $request->client_id,
        'product_id' => $request->product_id,

    ]);
    return redirect('admin/invoices/' . $invoices->id);
}
```

this stores an invoice into invoice table but i want to get the client_id and product_id or ids cause it must be multiple products and save them into invoice_product table which migration is down here

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('invoice_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('client_id');
        $table->integer('product_id');
        $table->integer('product_quantity');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: I wrote an answer about this here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/33552055/2131039](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33552055/2131039)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to insert data into intermediate or pivot table for many to many relationshiop
you can use attach eloquent method like below

```
$invoice->products()->attach($product_id)
$product->invoices()->attach($invoice_id)
```

but your invoice product migration looks a bit odd it should be like this

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('invoice_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('invoice_id'); // id of the invoice table
        $table->integer('product_id'); // id of the product table
        $table->integer('product_quantity'); // client_id should go to the invoice table
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: oya that was my miswring sorry for that yes and ok i try that to see what happens :)

Comment: should i write that in store function  ??

Comment: i mean this is my controller for storing that i use make command should i do it in here ?  $invoices = Invoice::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'client_id' => $request->client_id,
        ]);

Comment: you can write it any where you need @Farshad :)