# Laravel Many To Many Update Specific Field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have many to many relationship. In postman I pass find_id and status.

My query is like: UPDATE finds_user SET status = TRUE WHERE find_id = 2 AND user_id = 1.

I do it now like that:

```
DB::table('finds_user')
    ->where('find_id', '=', $request->find_id)
    ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
    ->update(['status' => $request->status]);
```

How I can do it with Eloquent instead of DB Query Builder?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a pivot table using Eloquent in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543897/how-to-update-a-pivot-table-using-eloquent-in-laravel-5)

Comment: No. I just want convert db query to eloquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have tow condition for update:

1- find_id = 2

2-  user_id = 1.

suppose the relation name in the user model called 'finds'
the query will look like this:

```
User::find(1)->finds()->newPivotQuery()->where('find_id',2)->update(['status'=>true])
```

and if you have a model for the pivot table with name like "FindUser":

```
FindUser::where('user_id',$user->id)->where('find_id',2)->update(['status'=>true]);
```

Comment: yes, it is, the method newPivotQuery() make the query directly for the pivot table, i have tested it

Comment: you could do:

$user->finds()->newPivotQuery()->where('find_id',2)->update(['status'=>true]);

will give the same result

Comment: what is the name of the many to many relation between user and find models?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211961/discussion-between-omr-and-johnsmith).