# Laravel edit pivot table directly

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table

I have a database, `carpark` and `car` records are linked by `car_park` pivot table.

Some rows in my pivot table (`car_park`)

```
id | carpark_id | car_id | in_date    | out_date
1  | 1          | 1      | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-30
2  | 1          | 2      | 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-28
3  | 1          | 1      | 2020-03-01 | 2020-03-31
....
```

In my carpark model, I have following entry:

```
public function cars() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Cars')->withPivot(['id', 'in_date', 'out_date']);
    }
```

Save I need to update pivot table row id 1,  I am not able to use

```
$carpark->$cars()->updateExistingPivot($car_id, $in_date, $out_date );
```

because the above statement will update both row id 1 and 3.

How can I update the pivot table with the pivot table row id?

Comment: Follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543897/how-to-update-a-pivot-table-using-eloquent-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 1):

Using `wherePivot` to find out pivot id

```
$carpark->cars()->wherePivot('id',1)->update(['in_date'=>'','out_date '=>'']);
```